# MariaDB/MySQL foreign key constraint: possible to request cascade at time of delete?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, mariadb, cascade

I have used PHP code to preserve database integrity for years, but now I am switching from MyISAM to InnoDB and thought it might be nice to utilize foreign key constraints, letting the DB carry more of the load. But I want to confirm with the user before doing a cascade, so the constraints would be declared as `ON DELETE RESTRICT`. When I get the error, I would let the user know that there are dependent records and how many, and if they say, "Sure, delete them," it would be nice to let the database do a cascading delete. Is it possible to tell a specific `DELETE` statement to go ahead and cascade? I expected an option or something on the `DELETE` command (e.g. pseudocode `DELETE FROM table WHERE ... CASCADE TO child-table`), but I didn't see anything.

Example (very standard many-to-many):

```
CREATE TABLE `person` (
  `PersonID` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `FullName` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  <many other fields>,
  PRIMARY KEY (`PersonID`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
CREATE TABLE `category` (
  `CategoryID` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Category` varchar(60) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`CategoryID`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
CREATE TABLE `percat` (
  `PersonID` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `CategoryID` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (`PersonID`,`CategoryID`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`PersonID`) REFERENCES `person`(`PersonID`) ON DELETE RESTRICT,
  FOREIGN KEY (`CategoryID`) REFERENCES `category`(`CategoryID`) ON DELETE RESTRICT
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=ascii COLLATE=ascii_bin;
```

I found [How to cascade-delete temporarily or on-demand?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42748910/how-to-cascade-delete-temporarily-or-on-demand) but: (a) it's for SQLServer, not MySQL (well, technically I'm using MariaDB 10.2.4, if that makes a difference), so I don't know if I have additional options available to me, and (b) such stored procedure code wouldn't be any simpler than the PHP code I already have (and less visible when I'm developing), so I don't see the point in swapping one for the other.

Comment: Are you saying you don't know about `ON DELETE CASCADE`, or that you want to temporarily change from RESTRICT to CASCADE? PS implementation by dropping the restrict, add the cascade, update, drop the delete, add the cascade pushes as much as possible into the DBMS.

Comment: I know about `ON DELETE CASCADE` - I'm talking about a temporary change, or more accurately, a *local exception*. I'm concerned about changing to cascade by `ALTER TABLE`, which would affect the whole system and perhaps cause unintended cascading by other concurrent users. Also, if something dies during a step between the two `ALTER TABLE` statements, it might not be restored to RESTRICT. So your suggestion sounds risky to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer:  No.

Longer answer:

The answer is simple-minded:  FKs are simple-minded.  When you ask for more than trivial actions, you are asking for too much of FKs, and you need to build the "business logic" into your application.

Ditto for Triggers.

MySQL (and MariaDB) have always been "lean and mean" compared to the heavy hitters.  FKs exist as a check on a feature list "yes, we have FKs, too".  So, anything esoteric in the details of FKs are quite likely missing.

Sometimes the syntax is implemented without any real code behind it -- `CHECK`; `INDEX(x DESC)`.  (The latter is finally being implemented in 8.0, but I would estimate the number of use cases to be somewhere around one in a thousand.)

Comment: Okay, thanks. I was starting to think that was the answer, but I wanted confirmation. I'll keep using PHP to do my best to catch everything, and just add the FKs as a safety net. I'm content with "lean and mean" - I want my DB to be fast.

Comment: Then don't use FKs if you already know that is no chance of a FK violation.  Checking an FK does take some effort.

Comment: "...if you already know that is no chance..." I can't tell if you are being tongue-in-cheek or you have more confidence than me in my ability to write bug-free code! ;-)

Comment: As for performance, what I read seemed to indicate that the effort is only when deleting (or updating a primary key field's value), which wouldn't bother me. Does it also slow down reads? If so, that would be a concern. I know that MyISAM is considered faster for reads than InnoDB (there seems to be widely varying opinions on how much faster), but FKs is not the reason I decided to switch - MyISAM seems to overall be in the process of being phased out. BTW, I liked your migration guide (http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/myisam2innodb)!

Comment: I have not actually moved any real data yet - I'm preparing a server move, and using the opportunity to review technologies as I go. But if it's best to stick with MyISAM a while longer, I can do that. My use case is relatively low numbers of data (the most voluminous many-many associative table in the most active DB instance is still less than 150,000 rows, and most are ***far*** less), but some of my queries are complex joins with subqueries, group concats, etc., which get slow. And I make no money on this, so I keep it on minimal hardware.

Comment: FKs are checked during `INSERT`; not during reads.  (An FK implicitly creates an `INDEX`, which may be used to speed up `JOINs`, but the equivalent index could be created without the FK constraint.)

Comment: _MyISAM being faster is an OLD wives-tale!_  Lots of _recent_ benchmarks show that InnoDB has at least caught up with MyISAM in _every_ area except disk space.

Comment: Due to the way that InnoDB clusters the PK with the data, InnoDB is _better_ than MyISAM for many:many tables.  More info [_here_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table).